# JQuery UserEdit page password checking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

"I want to change the password to include at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 number, and be at least 7 characters long in the user information editing section. In the code I wrote, when I click on the edit menu, it goes to the 'Password must be at least 7 characters' else block, and the password field comes up empty. Even though the password condition is incorrect, it still accepts it. What is the mistake here? How can I fix it?"

```
$.ajax(
              {
            type: "POST",
            url:  "@Url.Action("GetUserModalList")",
            data: {
              id: data.userId,
            },
              error: function (result) {

            },
            success: function (result) {
                 console.log(result);
                  if (result) {
                          var hasNumber = /[0-9]+/;
                          var hasUpperChar = /[A-Z]+/;
                          var hasMinimum7Chars = /.{7,}/;

                          dtGrid.ajax.reload(null, false);
                          $(".Name").val(result.name);
                          $(".Surname").val(result.surname);
                          $(".Email").val(result.email);
                          $(".Username").val(result.userName);
                          $(".Usertype").val(result.usertype);

                           if (hasMinimum7Chars.test(result.password)) {
                              if (hasNumber.test(result.password)) {
                                if (hasUpperChar.test(result.password)) {
                                     $(".Password").val(result.password);

                                     $(".black-screen").show();
                                     $j('#userList').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                                     var table = $j('#userList').DataTable();
                                     table.draw('page');
                                 } else {
                                     alert("Password must contain at least one capital letter.
");
                                    }
                               } else {
                                  alert("The password must contain at least one number.");
                                  }
                             } else {
                                alert("Password must contain at least 7 characters.");
                                }
                         } else {

                         }
                     }
```